# Google Colaboratory Export Data Frame

Tags: dataframe, google-colaboratory

Im using google colaboratory to run some models. I was able to upload a csv file with features in google drive, import it in and run models on that data. I want to export the final dataframe out to csv. Cant find a way to do that, please advise.

```
df.to_csv('df.csv', index=False)
```

This runs without an error, but I cant find where the file is saved.

Or let me know if there is a better way to export my df out.

Answer (score 6):

You can download the data back to your local machine with

```
from google.colab import files
files.download('df.csv')
```

Comment: do we have to download the created dataframe to local machine in order to use it again in Colab? Is there a way to create a copy of the df in Colab so that we could use it directly without downloading it? I'm concerned of potential error during the downloading and uploading process

Comment: You can save it to Google Drive, or cloud (GCS, S3). Then mount it to Colab.

Comment: When I use `df.to_csv('df.csv', index=False)` did I not save the file? How should I do it?

Comment: It's too long to explain here. Some snippet. `from google.colab import drive`, and `drive.mount('drive')`. Search for it in other questions.

Answer (score 2):

You can find answer here:
[Exporting Data from google colab to local machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49394737/exporting-data-from-google-colab-to-local-machine)

So what you need to do is:
- open the left pane
- select 'Files' tab
- click 'Refresh'
- right click the file, then download