# Exporting Data from google colab to local machine

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

How to export data frames which are created in google colab to your local machine?

I have cleaned a data set on google colab. Now I want to export the data frame to my local machine. 
`df.to_csv` is saving file to the virtual machine and not my local machine.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I download a pandas Dataframe in Google Colab?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48854943/how-can-i-download-a-pandas-dataframe-in-google-colab)

Answer (score 85):

Try this

```
from google.colab import files
files.download("data.csv")
```

Update(Sep 2018): now it's even easier

- open the left pane
- select 'Files' tab
- click 'Refresh'
- right click the file, then download

Update (Jan 2020): the UI changes

- click on the `folder icon` on the left pane (3rd icon)
- click 'Refresh'
- right click the file, then download

Comment: can we download the dataframes created in colab directly into g drive isntead of local.

Comment: @Shubh You can use `drive.mount(...)` then just `!cp` your file.

Comment: What about download an entire folder to your local machine? Everything I see is about downloading a single .csv file, but nothing in relation to download the entire folder. TY

Comment: To download the folder, you can zip it first with `!zip -r file.zip folder_name`, then download `file.zip`.

Comment: It gives me error: `'list' object has no attribute 'download'`

Comment: data frame... is missing.

Answer (score 51):

Try this:

First you can save the file using pandas `to_csv` functionality later on you can download that file using google colab files functionality.

```
from google.colab import files
df.to_csv('filename.csv') 
files.download('filename.csv')
```

Comment: if i do df.to_csv('filename.csv')  , it doesn't do anything , even if I import the google.colab files

Answer (score 4):

> #### [Downloading files to your local file system](https://colab.research.google.com/notebooks/snippets/drive.ipynb#scrollTo=hauvGV4hV-Mh)
>
> `files.download` will invoke a browser download of the file to your local computer.
>
> ```py
> from google.colab import files
>
> with open('example.txt', 'w') as f:
>   f.write('some content')
>
> files.download('example.txt')
> ```

Answer (score 1):

You can download the csv to your associated google drive.
First you must install PyDrive.

```
!pip install -U -q PyDrive
from pydrive.auth import GoogleAuth
from pydrive.drive import GoogleDrive
from google.colab import auth
from google.colab import files
from oauth2client.client import GoogleCredentials

auth.authenticate_user()
gauth = GoogleAuth()
gauth.credentials = GoogleCredentials.get_application_default()
drive = GoogleDrive(gauth)
```

This will generate a token in a browser for you to then paste into an input box that will be shown in your notebook.

Save your pandas data frame
 `df.to_csv('mydataframe.csv', sep='\t')`

To keep things neat you can create a new folder in your drive and then use the following:

`file_list = drive.ListFile({'q': "'root' in parents and trashed=false"}).GetList()
for file1 in file_list:
  print('title: %s, id: %s' % (file1['title'], file1['id']))`

which will list the files and folders in your google drive and their id that you will need for the following step.

`file = drive.CreateFile({'parents':[{u'id': '`*id of folder you want to save in*`'}]}) file.SetContentFile("mydataframe.csv")
file.Upload()`

It will now be in your google drive in the given folder.

Comment: though this code is helpful for a different question, I don't believe it answers this one.  I believe the OP is asking how to get the file from colab/google drive to the local machine...not how to get the file to google drive.